# Adding icons to image on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm creating a project where when you click on an image, a pin should be placed on that exact location. It needs to work on different screen sizes/browsers etc.

I've sampled some code from other questions on here, and had a thorough Google. I seem to not be grasping something!

When there is any other content on the page, the offset is incorrect. See below gifs.
[image: No extra page content]

[image: Extra content]

Floorplan example - source Google. All credit to original author.
[image]

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <script src="fontawesome.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <div>
        I'm another element on the page!
        <ul>Cool</ul>
        <ul>Noice</ul>
    </div>

    <div id="floorplan">
        <img id="floorplanImg" src="floorplan-example.png" alt="Floorplan Example Image" />
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        document.getElementById('floorplanImg').addEventListener('click', function (event) {
            bounds = this.getBoundingClientRect();
            var left = bounds.left;
            var top = bounds.top;
            var x = event.pageX - left - window.scrollX;
            var y = event.pageY - top - window.scrollY;
            var cw = this.clientWidth
            var ch = this.clientHeight
            var iw = this.naturalWidth
            var ih = this.naturalHeight
            var px = x / cw * iw
            var py = y / ch * ih

            // Testing 
            var xOffset = event.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
            var yOffset = event.pageY - this.offsetTop;
            // End Testing

            var previousModals = document.getElementById('newOfficeLocation');
            if (previousModals != null) {
                previousModals.remove();
            }
            var newLocation = document.createElement('div');
            var floorplan = document.getElementById('floorplan');

            newLocation.innerHTML = `
            <div id="newOfficeLocation" style="z-index: 1000;">
                <div id="dragContainer">
                <div id="item">
                    <span style="font-size: 2em; color: Tomato;">
                        <i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>`;

            floorplan.appendChild(newLocation);
            var newLoc = document.getElementById('newOfficeLocation');

            newLoc.style.position = "absolute";
            newLoc.style.top = py + "px";
            newLoc.style.left = px + "px";

            console.log('=================================');
            console.log('NEWLOC X: ' + newLoc.style.left);
            console.log('NEWLOC Y: ' + newLoc.style.top);

        });

    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because your appended absolute positioned element doesn't find any parent which is not static positioned, so it positions according to body element. So the solution is to add `position: relative` to the div with `floorplan` id.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply! That seems to have got it working. Just need to make it so the point of the icon is where you click.. Thanks again though!

Comment: Not at all. I thought that is just a little adjustment and you can do it by yourself so did not mention it.

Comment: Hi, me again :D I added this, and it makes the marker point go where you mouse pointer is.. But is there a better way of doing it then hard coding it in?
```py = py - 38;
px = px - 11;
newLoc.style.top = py + "px";
newLoc.style.left = px + "px";```

Comment: yeah sure you can do it
by adding this line: `newLoc.style.transform = "translate(-50%, -100%)";`
this is not like in the gif version because i thought the pointer should be at the bottom tip of the icon, but if you want exact center you can do `newLoc.style.transform = "translate(-50%, -50%)";`

Comment: whatever you add no matter what height or what width the thing you add has transform translate will always get that element's center or bottom or wherever you want with the help of percents